# Using aliases in PHP script to join 1 table twice for 2 different outputs

Tags: php, mysql, sql

In one table I have team name and team ID. In another table I have Winner and Runner up which are both linked to team ID (but I need to change the ID to team name using an alias). I need to link the winner and runner up with the team name from the teams table. Can anyone help me with it to display both winner and runner up instead of the team ID number. The images below should explain it better than me.

I can get it so the table works without using an Alias but can only get either the winner or runner up column to work. On image 4 it displays the team ID but I need it to display the Team name. Team name and Team ID are linked on the teams table in the database.

I've been told to use inner joins as such:

```
INNER JOIN teams t_winner ON tournament_info.winner = t_winner.team_id
INNER JOIN teams t_runner ON tournament_info.winner = t_runner.team_id
```

Then use:

```
<td align="center"><?php echo $row["t_runner.team_name"]; ?></td>
```

to display the output but doesn't seem to work.

Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <table align="left" width="100%" border="1" style="border-collapse:collapse;">
        <tr>
            <th><strong>Game Name</strong></th>
            <th><strong>Tournament Name</strong></th>
            <th><strong>Winner</strong></th>
            <th><strong>Runner Up</strong></th>
            <th><strong>End Date</strong></th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <?php
        $count=1;
        $sel_query="SELECT  *
    FROM tournament_info 

    INNER JOIN games ON tournament_info.game = games.id 
    INNER JOIN tournaments ON tournament_info.tournament = tournaments.tournament_id
    INNER JOIN teams t_winner ON tournament_info.winner = t_winner.team_id
    INNER JOIN teams t_runner ON tournament_info.runner_up = t_runner.team_id
    GROUP BY tournament_name
    ORDER BY finish_date DESC
    LIMIT 10";

        $result = mysqli_query($con,$sel_query);

        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) { ?>
            <td align="center"><?php
                if(!empty($row["game_url"])){ ?>
                    <a href="<?= $row["game_url"]; ?>"><?= $row["game_name"]; ?></a>
                <?php }else {
                    echo $row["game_name"];
                }
                ?></td>
            <td align="center"><?php
                if(!empty($row["tournament_url"])){ ?>
                    <a href="<?= $row["tournament_url"]; ?>"><?= $row["tournament_name"]; ?></a>
                <?php }else {
                    echo $row["tournament_name"];
                }
                ?></td>

            <td align="center"><?php echo $row["team_name.t_winner"]; ?></td>
            <td align="center"><?php echo $row["team_name.t_runner"]; ?></td>
            <td align="center"><?php echo date('F j, Y', strtotime($row["finish_date"])); ?></td>

            </tr>
            <?php $count++; } ?>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</html>
```

[image: WEBSITE TABLE OUTPUT]
[image: Tournament info table (holds all the data)]
[image: Teams Table]

[image: Image of table working with team ID]

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Is this **really** a PHP problem? Why not try to resolve this purely in SQL?

Comment: It's not my database, it was created by someone else. I just can't figure out why it's not working whilst using an Alias. Any help would be great, I am stuck on it.

Comment: using SELECT * is always a bad choice, you should name all columns with unique names

Comment: Even if this is not your database: what have you tried to resolve the problem? What does "not working" mean in context of that alias?

Comment: I am reaching out to other people as I been researching Alias's and changed my code so many times, it's getting very frustrating. I just cannot get a winner and runner up output on the table.

Comment: Please add all clarification to your question by editing it. This should also explain how the output should look like. Share the table structure, sample input data, and the expected output

Comment: Just formatting your code I noticed a few problems - you're missing an opening `<tr>` in your loop, and `$conn` is not defined.  You haven't told us what "*doesn't seem to work*" means, so I have no idea if those are enough to cause the problems you're seeing.

Comment: Have you tried running the SQL query in a MySQL client, to see if the result set looks like what you need and expected?

Comment: I have added a further image. I can get the table to display the team ID in the winner and runner up column but I need it to display the Team name. Team name and Team ID are linked on the teams table in the database. I just am unsure how to interlink it as it requires 2 joins to the same table. The rest of the code and connection (hidden) work fine. It is just that one bit with the team ID